# Touch Began on Scrollview for dismiss keyboard

Tags: c#, ios, touch, xamarin, uigesturerecognizer

`UIViewcontroller.View` added `ScrollView`.

for `scrollview` i added `textfields`.  5 `textfields` in a row.

I want to dismiss keyboard `textField.ResignFirstResponder ();` will dismiss the keyboard.

Since its `scrollView` is added to view controller view  `View.addSubView(Scroll_View);`

So, I used `touchesBegan` class to dismiss keyboard.

```
public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);
        UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;


        if (touch.LocationInView (scroll_View))
        {
            // the touch event happened inside the UIView imgTouchMe.
            textField.ResignFirstResponder ();              
        }
    }
```

It shows an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UITouch' to`System.Drawing.Point' (CS0029) (IOS)

Is there any way I can dismiss keyboard.

@all 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: LocationInView returns a point. What are you comparing it against in the if statement?

Comment: Can you explain where and possibly how you want the keyboard to resign? It's not clear.

Comment: @latenitecoder On scroll view i added 5 textfields and scroll view is added to uiviewcontroller.view.  on touch scrollview other then textfields I want dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);
    this.View.EndEditing (true);
}
```

Easy way , try it.